# How to add user custom fields to the edit profile form?

Tags: joomla

I had to add a series of custom fields to the joomla registration form. Thanks to the [guide](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2AyCzb2vTaU) I managed to do it, both for the registration form and for the administrator form.

The process I followed for this are the following:

1. Added the fields to the users table
2. Added the fields in joomla user entity `/library/src/user/user.php`
3. Added the fields and definition to `/components/com_users/model/forms/registration.xml` file to update the registration form
4. Added the fields and definition to `administrator/components/com_users/model/forms/user.xml` file to update the user edition form for user with administrator role

Now I require the user to be able to change their profile data with the inthe fields that were created manually. To do this I added a link to the menu
form to edit profile, here I expected to see all user fields, both native and custom created, but instead I obtain only the native fields, although upon inspecting the object (user) I can access all the user fields.

I created the fields by hand and then I expected that when they were saved they would persist, but it is not, when sending the form only the native data is updated and not the custom fields.

When I inspect, I see that a component named k2 is the one that facilitates this profile editing form, I am new to joomla and its ecosystem
Could you please give me guidance on how to implement this task?

Greetings and thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Do not edit core components**.

There is a way to do the same using Profile plugin.

https://docs.joomla.org/Creating_a_profile_plugin

Go through above link and create a new profile plugin.

Answer (score 1):

This is not the way to add extra user fields. What will you do if you need to update Joomla. Joomla releases security updates at regular intervals. First you need to create a user plugin and then you add whatever user fields you need. I found a detailed description here, you also can have a look. if still you get any doubts you can ask me here in comments.

https://smartyblog.com/adding-custom-fields-to-joomla-registration-using-profile-plugin/